# Does Cython support the ternary style if statement (if ? then : else)?

Tags: c, programming-languages, if-statement, cython

I forget the technical term for the `(if ? then : else)` format in C/C++. Also, is this syntax supported in the Cython (a C variant of Python)?

I need to know the technical name so I can lookup if Cython supports this feature.

UPDATE: **Does anyone know if Cython supports this?**

**Solution**: In cython/python this is written as `(b if a else c)` compare to `(a ? b : c)`

Comment: I would say this is a dupe, but I can't exactly blame you for being unable to search for the duplicates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called the ternary *conditional* operator. It's often just called the ternary operator, but being ternary is not necessarily (but in practice usually is) unique to the conditional operator.

EDIT: In regards to whether Cython supports `(x ? y : z)`, it appears not to based on some preliminary Googling. But Python (and theoretically Cython I think? Disclaimer: I don't use Cython) supports the same result (if/else expression) with `(y if x else z)`. EDIT 2: The Cython documentation I've found says that it works the same as in regular Python.

Answer (score 1):

It's often called the ternary operator, or inline if.

Comment: It's the ternary _conditional_ operator. Would you call `+` _the_ binary operator?

Comment: @Chris *The* binary operator is obviously `>>`. :o)

Comment: @Chris: It's the *only* ternary operator in C, while `+` is not the *only* binary operator.

Answer (score 0):

ternary operator.

Comment: It's the ternary _conditional_ operator. Would you call `+` _the_ binary operator?